# Delete CloudFormation stack if CodeBuild fails

Tags: integration-testing, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have a Stage in CodePipeline that deploys CloudFormation templates to generate environments on the fly to perform integration testing. I would like to erase those environment if the integration tests fail but I do not know how to approach the issue. I was thinking on adding a CloudWatch event to trigger a lambda but then I have the constraint of the 5 minutes timeout for the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking on adding a CloudWatch event to trigger a lambda but then I have the constraint of the 5 minutes timeout for the lambda.

This is the approach I'd recommend. CodePipeline emits CloudWatch events including when an action fails: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html

Regarding the 5 minute timeout, this shouldn't be a problem given the CloudFormation DeleteStack API will return straight away even though it will take CloudFormation a few minutes to actually delete the stack.